# Phalcon fire event from controller

Tags: php, events, phalcon

I am using the Phalcon micro application as my REST web service. I want to add an event to the application and fire this event from different places like controllers.
For example; if a user registers, the controller should fire a `userRegistered` event, and `userRegistered` should do some stuff.

How can I implement this?

```
interface IUsers
{
    function onUserRegistered();
}
```

Event class

```
class UsersActivities implements IUsers
{
    function onUserRegistered()
    {
        // TODO: Implement onUserRegistered() method.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check docs. It's pretty simple, create manager, creat listener(UsersActivities in your case i guess) and fire events in manager.

https://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/events.html